# Structure containing fields that know each other

Tags: rust

I have a set of objects that need to know each other to cooperate. These objects are stored in a container. I'm trying to get a very simplistic idea of how to architecture my code in Rust.

Let's use an analogy. A `Computer` contains:

- 1 `Mmu`
- 1 `Ram`
- 1 `Processor`

In Rust:

```
struct Computer {
    mmu: Mmu,
    ram: Ram,
    cpu: Cpu,
}
```

For anything to work, the `Cpu` needs to know about the `Mmu` it is linked to, and the `Mmu` needs to know the `Ram` it is linked to.

[image]

I do **not** want the `Cpu` to *aggregate by value* the `Mmu`. Their lifetimes differ: the `Mmu` can live its own life by itself. It just happens that I can plug it to the `Cpu`. However, there is no sense in creating a `Cpu` without an `Mmu` attached to it, since it would not be able to do its job. The same relation exists between `Mmu` and `Ram`.

Therefore:

- A `Ram` can live by itself.
- An `Mmu` needs a `Ram`.
- A `Cpu` needs an `Mmu`.

How can I model that kind of design in Rust, one with **a struct whose fields know about each other**.

In C++, it would be along the lines of:

>

```
struct Ram
{
};

struct Mmu
{
  Ram& ram;
  Mmu(Ram& r) : ram(r) {}
};

struct Cpu
{
  Mmu& mmu;
  Cpu(Mmu& m) : mmu(m) {}
};

struct Computer
{
    Ram ram;
    Mmu mmu;
    Cpu cpu;
    Computer() : ram(), mmu(ram), cpu(mmu) {}
};
```

Here is how I started translating that in Rust:

```
struct Ram;

struct Mmu<'a> {
    ram: &'a Ram,
}

struct Cpu<'a> {
    mmu: &'a Mmu<'a>,
}

impl Ram {
    fn new() -> Ram {
        Ram
    }
}

impl<'a> Mmu<'a> {
    fn new(ram: &'a Ram) -> Mmu<'a> {
        Mmu {
            ram: ram
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Cpu<'a> {
    fn new(mmu: &'a Mmu) -> Cpu<'a> {
        Cpu {
            mmu: mmu,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ram = Ram::new();
    let mmu = Mmu::new(&ram);
    let cpu = Cpu::new(&mmu);
}
```

That is fine and all, but now I just can't find a way to create the `Computer` struct.

I started with:

```
struct Computer<'a> {
    ram: Ram,
    mmu: Mmu<'a>,
    cpu: Cpu<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Computer<'a> {
    fn new() -> Computer<'a> {
        // Cannot do that, since struct fields are not accessible from the initializer
        Computer {
            ram: Ram::new(),
            mmu: Mmu::new(&ram),
            cpu: Cpu::new(&mmu),
        }

        // Of course cannot do that, since local variables won't live long enough
        let ram = Ram::new();
        let mmu = Mmu::new(&ram);
        let cpu = Cpu::new(&mmu);
        Computer {
            ram: ram,
            mmu: mmu,
            cpu: cpu,
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, whatever, I won't be able to find a way to reference structure fields between them. I thought I could come up with something by creating the `Ram`, `Mmu` and `Cpu` on the heap; and put that inside the struct:

```
struct Computer<'a> {
    ram: Box<Ram>,
    mmu: Box<Mmu<'a>>,
    cpu: Box<Cpu<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Computer<'a> {
    fn new() -> Computer<'a> {
        let ram = Box::new(Ram::new());
        // V-- ERROR: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a
        let mmu = Box::new(Mmu::new(&*ram));
        let cpu = Box::new(Cpu::new(&*mmu));
        Computer {
            ram: ram,
            mmu: mmu,
            cpu: cpu,
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah that's right, at this point in time Rust has no way to know that I'm going to transfer ownership of `let ram = Box::new(Ram::new())` to the `Computer`, so it will get a lifetime of `'a`.

I've been trying various more or less hackish ways to get that right, but I just can't come up with a clean solution. The closest I've come is to drop the reference and use an `Option`, but then all my methods have to check whether the `Option` is `Some` or `None`, which is rather ugly.

I think I'm just on the wrong track here, trying to map what I would do in C++ in Rust, but that doesn't work. That's why I would need help finding out what is the idiomatic Rust way of creating this architecture.

Comment: "the Mmu can live its own life by itself" - but do you want to share the MMU across multiple CPUs at the same time?

Comment: "> do you want to share the MMU across multiple CPUs at the same time?" that is not required (and doesn't work with the refs as explained here). That would be a nice feature tho.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't aggregate by value. You only say an `Mmu` needs to be able to live on its own, but a `Cpu` containing a `Mmu` by value doesn't prevent that. You can have an `Mmu` floating around doing whatever a free-range `Mmu` does, and at some point move it into a `Cpu` (and even move it back out, invaliding the `Cpu` in the process). The only thing you lose is the ability to have an MMU shared by multiple CPUs (or a RAM shared by multiple MMUs), which is semantically questionable. It could probably be done with `Rc` though.

Comment: "> You can have an Mmu, and then move it into a Cpu (and even move it back out, invaliding the Cpu in the process)." Well there are 2 reasons: 1) It doesn't really make much sense with the analogy. The Ram is not a part of the Mmu. Later on, the Mmu will be able to switch between a Ram and a Cartridge. The cartridge is also clearly not semantically a part of the Mmu. 2) Wouldn't that mean copying tons of stuff around? Imagine the Ram is one big huge `u8` array.

Comment: @AurélienVallée Aggregation does not imply a part-of relationship of the entities modeled. It only implies ownership, and ownership is certainly appropriate (though not something you'd normally consider). And yes, moving copies, but that also applies to passing parameters, returning values, ordinary local assignments, etc. so if the type is big enough for moving to be prohibitive, there are already many good reasons to `Box` it (which keeps ownership but makes moves as cheap as a pointer copy). Plus, if it's more than a megabyte, it shouldn't be on the stack anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this answer I will discuss two approaches to solving this problem, one in safe Rust with zero dynamic allocation and very little runtime cost, but which can be constricting, and one with dynamic allocation that uses unsafe invariants.

### The Safe Way (`Cell<Option<&'a T>`)

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Computer<'a> {
    ram: Ram,
    mmu: Mmu<'a>,
    cpu: Cpu<'a>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Ram;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cpu<'a> {
    mmu: Cell<Option<&'a Mmu<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Mmu<'a> {
    ram: Cell<Option<&'a Ram>>,
}

impl<'a> Computer<'a> {
    fn new() -> Computer<'a> {
        Computer {
            ram: Ram,
            cpu: Cpu {
                mmu: Cell::new(None),
            },
            mmu: Mmu {
                ram: Cell::new(None),
            },
        }
    }

    fn freeze(&'a self) {
        self.mmu.ram.set(Some(&self.ram));
        self.cpu.mmu.set(Some(&self.mmu));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let computer = Computer::new();
    computer.freeze();

    println!("{:?}, {:?}, {:?}", computer.ram, computer.mmu, computer.cpu);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c3abed32895507cc5c1094a85ef5ad9b&version=stable)

Contrary to popular belief, self-references *are* in fact possible in safe Rust, and even better, when you use them Rust will continue to enforce memory safety for you.

The main "hack" needed to get self, recursive, or cyclical references using `&'a T` is the use of a `Cell<Option<&'a T>` to contain the reference. You won't be able to do this without the `Cell<Option<T>>` wrapper.

The clever bit of this solution is splitting initial creation of the struct from proper initialization. This has the unfortunate downside that it's possible to use this struct incorrectly by initializing it and using it before calling `freeze`, but it can't result in memory unsafety without further usage of `unsafe`.

The initial creation of the struct only sets the stage for our later hackery - it creates the `Ram`, which has no dependencies, and sets the `Cpu` and `Mmu` to their unusable state, containing `Cell::new(None)` instead of the references they need.

Then, we call the `freeze` method, which deliberately holds a borrow of self with lifetime `'a`, or the full lifetime of the struct. After we call this method, the compiler will prevent us from getting mutable references to the `Computer` *or* moving the `Computer`, as either could invalidate the reference that we are holding. The `freeze` method then sets up the `Cpu` and `Mmu` appropriately by setting the `Cell`s to contain `Some(&self.cpu)` or `Some(&self.ram)` respectively.

After `freeze` is called our struct is ready to be used, but only immutably.

### The Unsafe Way (`Box<T>` never moves `T`)

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::mem;

// CRUCIAL INFO:
//
// In order for this scheme to be safe, Computer *must not*
// expose any functionality that allows setting the ram or
// mmu to a different Box with a different memory location.
//
// Care must also be taken to prevent aliasing of &mut references
// to mmu and ram. This is not a completely safe interface,
// and its use must be restricted.
struct Computer {
    ram: Box<Ram>,
    cpu: Cpu,
    mmu: Box<Mmu>,
}

struct Ram;

// Cpu and Mmu are unsafe to use directly, and *must only*
// be exposed when properly set up inside a Computer
struct Cpu {
    mmu: *mut Mmu,
}
struct Mmu {
    ram: *mut Ram,
}

impl Cpu {
    // Safe if we uphold the invariant that Cpu must be
    // constructed in a Computer.
    fn mmu(&self) -> &Mmu {
        unsafe { mem::transmute(self.mmu) }
    }
}

impl Mmu {
    // Safe if we uphold the invariant that Mmu must be
    // constructed in a Computer.
    fn ram(&self) -> &Ram {
        unsafe { mem::transmute(self.ram) }
    }
}

impl Computer {
    fn new() -> Computer {
        let ram = Box::new(Ram);

        let mmu = Box::new(Mmu {
            ram: unsafe { mem::transmute(&*ram) },
        });
        let cpu = Cpu {
            mmu: unsafe { mem::transmute(&*mmu) },
        };

        // Safe to move the components in here because all the
        // references are references to data behind a Box, so the
        // data will not move.
        Computer {
            ram: ram,
            mmu: mmu,
            cpu: cpu,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e3522a3cad0eb91e43a03b5702061670&version=stable)

*NOTE*: This solution is not completely safe given an unrestricted interface to `Computer` - care must be taken to not allow aliasing or removal of the `Mmu` or `Ram` in the public interface of Computer.

This solution instead uses the invariant that data stored inside of a `Box` will never move - it's address will never change - as long as the `Box` remains alive. Rust doesn't allow you to depend on this in safe code, since moving a `Box` can cause the memory behind it be deallocated, thereby leaving a dangling pointer, but we can rely on it in unsafe code.

The main trick in this solution is to use raw pointers into the contents of the `Box<Mmu>` and `Box<Ram>` to store references into them in the `Cpu` and `Mmu` respectively. This gets you a mostly safe interface, and doesn't prevent you from moving the `Computer` around or even mutating it in restricted cases.

### An Ending Note

All of this said, I don't think either of these should really be the way you approach this problem. Ownership is a central concept in Rust, and it permeates the design choices of almost all code. If the `Mmu` owns the `Ram` and the `Cpu` owns the `Mmu`, that's the relationship you should have in your code. If you use `Rc`, you can even maintain the ability to share the underlying pieces, albeit immutably.

Comment: "to share the underlying pieces, albeit immutably" - which you can partially work around by using another [`Cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), if you need to.

Comment: Good and useful answer! Thanks!

Just a random note: I think you have to be careful in the `drop` methods. Say the `drop` for Mmu uses Ram. I'm not sure what Rust guarantees in terms of drop order. It's possible that Rust will first drop Ram, then try to drop Mmu, but uh-oh this tries to use the already-dropped Ram.

I suppose in such a case you would have to write a `drop` for Computer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding an *exploder* (a term I just made up). It's a function that consumes the value and returns all the constituent parts:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Mmu(u32);

impl Mmu {
    fn manage_that_memory(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1
    }
}

struct Cpu {
    mmu: Mmu,
}

impl Cpu {
    fn compute_like_a_computer(&mut self) {
        println!("Gonna compute! {:?}", self.mmu);
        self.mmu.manage_that_memory();
        println!("Computed! {:?}", self.mmu)
    }

    fn halt_and_catch_fire(self) -> Mmu {
        self.mmu
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mmu = Mmu(42);
    let mut cpu = Cpu { mmu: mmu };
    // println!("{:?}", mmu); // Consumed by the CPU, for now
    cpu.compute_like_a_computer();
    let mmu = cpu.halt_and_catch_fire();
    println!("{:?}", mmu); // And we get it again
}
```

Here, we go ahead and let the CPU have a MMU **by value**. Then, when we are done with the CPU, we break it down to the component parts which we can then reuse.